# int operators != and == when comparing to zero

Tags: c++, performance, assembly, machine-code

I've found that != and == are not the fastest ways for testing for zero or non-zero.

```
bool nonZero1 = integer != 0;
xor eax, eax
test ecx, ecx
setne al

bool nonZero2 = integer < 0 || integer > 0;
test ecx, ecx
setne al

bool zero1 = integer == 0;
xor eax, eax
test ecx, ecx
sete al

bool zero2 = !(integer < 0 || integer > 0);
test ecx, ecx
sete al
```

Compiler: VC++ 11
Optimization flags: /O2 /GL /LTCG

This is the assembly output for x86-32. The second versions of both comparisons were ~12% faster on both x86-32 and x86-64. However, on x86-64 the instructions were identical (first versions looked exactly like the second versions), but the second versions were still faster.

1. Why doesn't the compiler generate the faster version on x86-32?
2. Why are the second versions still faster on x86-64 when the assembly output is identical?

**EDIT: I've added benchmarking code. ZERO: 1544ms, 1358ms NON_ZERO: 1544ms, 1358ms**
http://pastebin.com/m7ZSUrcP
or
http://anonymouse.org/cgi-bin/anon-www.cgi/http://pastebin.com/m7ZSUrcP

Note: It's probably inconvenient to locate these functions when compiled in a single source file, because main.asm goes quite big. I had zero1, zero2, nonZero1, nonZero2 in a separate source file.

**EDIT2: Could someone with both VC++11 and VC++2010 installed run the benchmarking code and post the timings? It might indeed be a bug in VC++11.**

Comment: Would you provide the complete program you are using to benchmark the performance?

Comment: So how does it guarantee the rest of eax is zero if it's just skipping the xor?

Comment: Where are the `xor` instructions coming from? They don't look relevant to the test, so it should be part of the surrounding code.

Comment: What happens if you change the order? The compiler is smart enough to know that it has `xor`:ed `eax` *before* the first test and that that remains valid for the next...

Comment: NFRCR, did you really benchmark that as linear code? I assumed you just pasted them together to keep the size of the post down.

Comment: I've added benchmarking code now.

Comment: "I had zero1, zero2, nonZero1, nonZero2 in a separate compilation unit."... the most important optimization by far is inlining, and you prevented it?  No one cares about the performance of a tiny function that compares a number to zero.  They care how they should write that comparison inside a larger function (call inline function, use `!=`, use `> || <`).  Or else at least introduce a virtual call, which is the only realistic situation where this could happen as a standalone function.

Comment: Plus, cross-TU inlining is very common and the compiler can perfectly well do it for simple functions.

Comment: @Ben Voigt.

Take a look at the pastebin link. It's all in a single source file now. And performs the same way.

Comment: @Ben Voight. And it did inline at first as well. I actually turned off inlining and watched the timings go up 3x. So inlining for sure did work. Why would a separate source file prevent inlining? I had /LTCG.

Comment: @NFRCR: Showing all the optimization flags is appreciated ;)

Comment: @NFRCR: My bloody ISP has blocked pastebin ATM for some unknown reason. Could you post the code or let me know what vc11 is doing with the sources I posted? I don't have a vc11 compiler handy to compare stuff :/

Comment: @dirkgently

Try: http://anonymouse.org/cgi-bin/anon-www.cgi/http://pastebin.com/m7ZSUrcP

Comment: Ok, I've taken a look at this with the Visual C++ 2012 RC.  I've compiled your code with /O2 and /GL and I've gotten the same x86 assembly dump for each function.  Benchmark1 is _consistently_ 20% faster than Benchmark2 on my Core i5 540M (~1433 clocks vs. ~1800 clocks).  I get near identical results for x86 and x64.  So, I wonder if the generated code is better for some CPUs and worse for others?  (I am not a performance guru, so I don't know, but I figured I'd at least take a look and report my findings.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> EDIT: Saw OP's assembly listing for my code. I doubt this is even a *general bug with VS2011* now. This may simply be a special case bug for OP's code. I ran OP's code as-is with clang 3.2, gcc 4.6.2 and VS2010 and in all cases the *max differences* were at ~1%.

Just compiled the sources with suitable modifications to my `ne.c` file and the `/O2` and `/GL` flags. Here's the source

```
int ne1(int n) {
 return n != 0;
 }

 int ne2(int n) {
 return n < 0 || n > 0;
 }

 int ne3(int n) {
 return !(n == 0);
 }

int main() { int p = ne1(rand()), q = ne2(rand()), r = ne3(rand());}
```

and the corresponding assembly:

```
    ; Listing generated by Microsoft (R) Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 

    TITLE   D:\llvm_workspace\tests\ne.c
    .686P
    .XMM
    include listing.inc
    .model  flat

INCLUDELIB OLDNAMES

EXTRN   @__security_check_cookie@4:PROC
EXTRN   _rand:PROC
PUBLIC  _ne3
; Function compile flags: /Ogtpy
;   COMDAT _ne3
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_n$ = 8                         ; size = 4
_ne3    PROC                        ; COMDAT
; File d:\llvm_workspace\tests\ne.c
; Line 11
    xor eax, eax
    cmp DWORD PTR _n$[esp-4], eax
    setne   al
; Line 12
    ret 0
_ne3    ENDP
_TEXT   ENDS
PUBLIC  _ne2
; Function compile flags: /Ogtpy
;   COMDAT _ne2
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_n$ = 8                         ; size = 4
_ne2    PROC                        ; COMDAT
; Line 7
    xor eax, eax
    cmp eax, DWORD PTR _n$[esp-4]
    sbb eax, eax
    neg eax
; Line 8
    ret 0
_ne2    ENDP
_TEXT   ENDS
PUBLIC  _ne1
; Function compile flags: /Ogtpy
;   COMDAT _ne1
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_n$ = 8                         ; size = 4
_ne1    PROC                        ; COMDAT
; Line 3
    xor eax, eax
    cmp DWORD PTR _n$[esp-4], eax
    setne   al
; Line 4
    ret 0
_ne1    ENDP
_TEXT   ENDS
PUBLIC  _main
; Function compile flags: /Ogtpy
;   COMDAT _main
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_main   PROC                        ; COMDAT
; Line 14
    call    _rand
    call    _rand
    call    _rand
    xor eax, eax
    ret 0
_main   ENDP
_TEXT   ENDS
END
```

`ne2()` which used the `<`, `>` and `||` operators is **clearly** more expensive. `ne1()` and `ne3()` which use the `==` and `!=` operators respectively, are terser and equivalent.

Visual Studio 2011 is *in beta*. I would consider this as a bug. My tests with two other compilers namely *gcc 4.6.2* and *clang 3.2*, with the `O2` optimization switch yielded the exact same assembly for all three tests (that I had) on my Windows 7 box. Here's a summary:

```
$ cat ne.c

#include <stdbool.h>
bool ne1(int n) {
    return n != 0;
}

bool ne2(int n) {
    return n < 0 || n > 0;
}

bool ne3(int n) {
    return !(n != 0);
}

int main() {}
```

yields with gcc:

```
_ne1:
LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    4(%esp), %eax
    testl   %eax, %eax
    setne   %al
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE0:
    .p2align 2,,3
    .globl  _ne2
    .def    _ne2;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_ne2:
LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    4(%esp), %edx
    testl   %edx, %edx
    setne   %al
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE1:
    .p2align 2,,3
    .globl  _ne3
    .def    _ne3;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_ne3:
LFB2:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    4(%esp), %ecx
    testl   %ecx, %ecx
    sete    %al
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE2:
    .def    ___main;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section    .text.startup,"x"
    .p2align 2,,3
    .globl  _main
    .def    _main;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_main:
LFB3:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    andl    $-16, %esp
    call    ___main
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE3:
```

and with clang:

```
    .def     _ne1;
    .scl    2;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .text
    .globl  _ne1
    .align  16, 0x90
_ne1:
    cmpl    $0, 4(%esp)
    setne   %al
    movzbl  %al, %eax
    ret

    .def     _ne2;
    .scl    2;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .globl  _ne2
    .align  16, 0x90
_ne2:
    cmpl    $0, 4(%esp)
    setne   %al
    movzbl  %al, %eax
    ret

    .def     _ne3;
    .scl    2;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .globl  _ne3
    .align  16, 0x90
_ne3:
    cmpl    $0, 4(%esp)
    sete    %al
    movzbl  %al, %eax
    ret

    .def     _main;
    .scl    2;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .globl  _main
    .align  16, 0x90
_main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    calll   ___main
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

***My suggestion would be to file this as a bug with [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio).***

Note: I compiled them as C source since I don't think using the corresponding C++ compiler would make any significant change here.

Comment: Good test, but you've put the comparisons inside functions. The OP didn't provide any context and would do well to compile your version.

Comment: Compiling short snippets as independent functions isn't interesting.  The optimization that happens after they get inlined at a call site is more important.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I think my tests with VS2010 (a compiler that has been released) seals the issue. Also, my (updated) source (that I used for VS2010) should answer whatever questions you have regarding independent functions.

Comment: Your new test is messed up, the compiler performed constant propagation, since it determined `n = 10` always.  And then, on top of that, it eliminated the function calls entirely, since the result wasn't used and there are no side effects.

Comment: shouldn't ne3 be `!(n == 0)`? (You have `!(n != 0)`)

Comment: @BenVoigt: Updated. This should suffice. I stand by my point that this is a bug than a rule.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Also, refrain from saying stuff like *Compiling short snippets as independent functions isn't interesting.* IMHO, that is the de-facto rule of posting on boards/working through issues. Also, that is how you test compilers.

Comment: @dirkgently: When it comes to optimizer questions, context is everything.

Comment: @dirkgently
Assembly output: http://anonymouse.org/cgi-bin/anon-www.cgi/http://pastebin.com/DVH8ex2P

If I use a constant instead of rand() these instuctions get optimized into something different. However this shouldn't matter since I also used std::generate() with rand() in my benchmarking code and it used the same exact instructions. So what should I think of this? An optimization that becomes a bug?

Comment: @NFRCR: I just ran your code with VS2010 `cl` on a x86. With both `NON_ZERO` and `ZERO` macros (separately of course!). The difference is ~1%. And I say difference because the numbers swing either way. The reason I used C was I didn't want to wade through the mangled names and the horror of iostreams in assembly. Also, note that a particular bit pattern may generate strange results (which is another reason for using `rand()` -- though `rand()` is not free from its failings).

Comment: @dirkgently

If you have more time you could move zero1, zero2, nonZero1, nonZero2 to a separate compilation unit (Test.h + Test.cpp perhaps). It would then be easier to locate the assemly output for these functions in Test.asm.

Comment: @NFRCR: I think the code is weighed down by quite a few other things. Did you try the code I posted? I could move your code around but I don't really see the point. Logically speaking, when the compiler has nothing else to work on, I see direct equality checks to be more efficient than two potential ordering checks (and an optional `OR`). My suggestion will be to ask the VS team directly.

Comment: @dirkgently

Yeah, I tried your code. The results are a few comments up.

Comment: IT'S NOT A BUG! How can it be a bug if the compiled code behaves as it should? It shows that there is room for improvement in the optimiser, but there's room for improvement in every optimiser. (That's a theorem, by the way.)

Comment: @TonyK: That is exactly what I call a bug. An obvious (one instruction compared to three -- *as written by the programmer*) one at that too. Also, try this with a few compilers. Then you start thinking about whether this is a bug or not.

Comment: @NFRCR: The assembly, I believe? That then sort of settles it for me. It's not even a bug. It is behaving exactly as it should. You may have run into a special scenario. But then, as I keep saying, talk to the VS team. They are great, prompt and I'm sure you'd have a far more reliable answer from them.

Comment: Visual C++ bugs may be reported on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio).

Comment: Also, it would be worth testing this with the [Visual C++ 2012 RC](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads) that was just released today.

Comment: FYI: I tested the OP's code with clang and gcc and again the differences were ~1% (or lower).

Comment: dirkgently: So a program that has room for improvement is *exactly what you call a bug*? We are not speaking the same language!

Comment: @TonyK: IIUC, you were talking about the optimizer in your previous comment. That is what I was referring to in my earlier comment.

Comment: dirkgently: Yes. An optimiser has a bug if it changes the behaviour of the program it is optimising. That is not the case here. All optimisers have room for improvement; as I think I already said, this is a theorem. Of mathematics.

Comment: @TonyK: It would also be a bug to degrade the performance of one instruction compared to that of three.

Comment: dirkgently: You're just not listening to me, are you? Oh well.

Comment: I am not sure that this is really a bug.  See my comment in response to the original question for conflicting benchmark data.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: I'd updated my answer a while back once I had a look at the assembly posted by OP and my tests with OP's code using three different compilers. Check out the edit at the top. I too don't think that there one version is better than the other.

Answer (score 123):

This is a great question, but I think you've fallen victim to the compiler's dependency analysis.

The compiler only has to clear the high bits of `eax` once, and they remain clear for the second version.  The second version would have to pay the price to `xor eax, eax` except that the compiler analysis proved it's been left cleared by the first version.

**The second version is able to "cheat" by taking advantage of work the compiler did in the first version.**

How are you measuring times?  Is it "(version one, followed by version two) in a loop", or "(version one in a loop) followed by (version two in a loop)"?

Don't do both tests in the same program (instead recompile for each version), or if you do, test both "version A first" and "version B first" and see if whichever comes first is paying a penalty.

---

Illustration of the cheating:

```
timer1.start();
double x1 = 2 * sqrt(n + 37 * y + exp(z));
timer1.stop();
timer2.start();
double x2 = 31 * sqrt(n + 37 * y + exp(z));
timer2.stop();
```

If `timer2` duration is less than `timer1` duration, we don't conclude that multiplying by 31 is faster than multiplying by 2.  Instead, we realize that the compiler performed common subexpression analysis, and the code became:

```
timer1.start();
double common = sqrt(n + 37 * y + exp(z));
double x1 = 2 * common;
timer1.stop();
timer2.start();
double x2 = 31 * common;
timer2.stop();
```

And the only thing proved is that multiplying by 31 is faster than computing `common`.  Which is hardly surprising at all -- multiplication is far far faster than `sqrt` and `exp`.

Comment: Benchmarking code added. I ran benchmark1 and benchmark2 separately, same results. The only difference is the first benchmark that runs, then it "warms up" and is a bit slower.

Comment: This is somewhat unrelated, but wouldn't a compiler optimize a multiplication by 31 to a `(common << 5) - common`?

Comment: @Matt: Not for floating-point multiplication it wouldn't ;)  For integer multiplication, yes I think most compilers know that trick, but depending on architecture it may or may not be faster.  IMUL by two is almost certainly converted to a left shift.